# How do I process form checkbox into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, checkboxlist

I want to get the selected values from the  processed into my database? How can Achieve that?

I'm just getting one result stored into the database. My goal is that each user can do a multiple selection from a list of receipts numbers under their accounts and then when they submit the request I want to get the selected receipt numbers in the database.

here is my form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="warehouse"><p><b><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Selecciona a continuación los recibos de bodega que deseas enviar :</b></p></label><br>


                                                    <?php
                                                        // Get the Client List
                                                        $qry4 = "SELECT
                                                                    projectId,
                                                                    clientId,
                                                                    projectName,
                                                                    store,                                                                      
                                                                    projectDeatils
                                                                FROM
                                                                    clientprojects
                                                                WHERE clientId = ".$clientId."";

                                                        $res4 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry4) or die('-4'.mysqli_error());
                                                        while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res4)) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <input   type="checkbox" name="warehouse" value="<?php echo $d['projectName']; ?>" >
                                                    <?php echo clean($d['store']); ?>&nbsp;  | &nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="index.php?page=viewProject&projectId=<?php echo clean($d['projectId']); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Ver En Detalle">
                                                    <?php echo clean($d['projectName']); ?></a>&nbsp;
                                                    :&nbsp;<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo clean($d['projectDeatils']); ?>"> <?php echo ellipsis($d['projectDeatils'],50); ?></a><br>


                                                    <?php } ?>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="input" name="submit" value="requestShipment" class="btn btn-success btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <?php echo $reqQuoteBtn; ?></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-icon" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> <?php echo $cancelBtn; ?></button>
            </div>
```

Here is my database connection:

```
    // New shipment Request
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'requestShipment') {
    // Validation
    if($_POST['warehouse'] == "") {
        $msgBox = alertBox($projTitleReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
    } else if($_POST['shipmentAddress'] == "") {
        $msgBox = alertBox($addressStreetWarning, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
    } else {
        $warehouse = $_POST['warehouse'];
        $shipmentAddress = $_POST['shipmentAddress'];
        $requestDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                            INSERT INTO
                                shipmentrequest(
                                    clientId,
                                    warehouse,
                                    shipmentAddress,
                                    requestDate
                                ) VALUES (
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?
                                )");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss',
            $clientId,
            $warehouse,
            $shipmentAddress,
            $requestDate
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Checkboxes need to have either unique names or get passed through as an array. Like `name='warehouse1'` and `name='warehouse2'` or you can give each one a name like this `name='warehouse[]'`. I would recommend the array approach because you can simply use PHP to loop through `$_POST['warehouse']`

Comment: The answer is iteration, just make sure you use the names as shown in @MonkeyZeus comment. And ,please, PHP processes the data from the checkboxes and saves it in to MySQL, get your flow/terminology right.